# Swift: Pushing a View controller on a UICollectionViewCell

Tags: swift, uicollectionviewcell, viewcontroller

I have a collection view that each cell has a tap gesture, when tapped I want to launch another ViewController, like I would do when using a navigation bar (the ViewController has a X button that is supposed to pop it).
I usually use self.navigationController?.present for this purpose, but in this case since it is a UICollectionViewCell, I cannot use present function.
I tried this but it did not work:

```
    func handleTap(){
        let storyboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)
        let controller = storyboard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "driver")
        self.window?.rootViewController?.presentedViewController?.addChildViewController(controller)
    }
```

For some reason it is all nil in the optionals. 
Is this even a logical approach? what would be a good solution to this problem?

Comment: Why are not using `didSelectItemAtindexPath` method of `UICollectionViewdelegate`.

Comment: This is something I do not know, will check it out!

Comment: @NiravD 's recommendations are right and the best way. Use this method and then you can present your VC by simply as self.present...

Comment: @Mannopson You cannot call `self.present` from the `UICollectionViewCell`.

Comment: @NiravD I think he meant that I should call self.present from the UICollectionView class

Comment: @Sharonica That might be possible. Have you try `didSelectItemAtindexPath` with your controller is it works for you?

Comment: @Sharonica Yeah! You're right!

Comment: Yes it works. Thank you all for the help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use this method to implement push segue.

```
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, didSelectItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    // handle tap events
    print("You selected cell #\(indexPath.item)!")

}
```

You can also use storyboard to perform the action